# how to write a shell script for creating an API gateway in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I have created an API Gateway in AWS using the UI, I want to automate this process and write a shell script which will create the API Gateway, same as I have configured it in AWS.

Comment: ... And your question is ? Perhaps devops SE is a good place to ask this question.

Comment: There are better way to manage cloud resources, probably you can check infrastructure as a code tool like AWS cloudformation, terraform, etc 
If this API gateway is used for serverless stack, then probably you can also check serverless framework which internally uses AWS cloudformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, I also recommend using better tools such as cloudformation to manage the infrastructure.

If you really want to use bash script, you can use AWS Cli commands in your bash script.

#### create API

> aws apigateway create-rest-api --name my-api

#### get root resource

> API=bs8fqo6bp0
>   aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id $API

#### create resource

> aws apigateway create-resource --rest-api-id $API  --path-part test \
>   --parent-id e8kitthgdb

here is an example from AWS docs, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example.html